# Trying to find the name of a movie that I (partly) know the plot of involving a small town and aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I am trying to find the name of a (possible) movie that I only know the plot of partly (since I don’t know the movie completely, it may contain some spoilers). As far as I know, it is as follows:

It takes place in a small normal town but after some point some man starts to stay awake at nights and realizes that every day people change their jobs and life each morning when they wake up, for example the butcher of the town becomes the mayor of the town, or the doctor of the town becomes the bar manager of the town, or the greengrocer of the town becones a housewife, etc., and people think they were doing that job/living that life for ages when they wake up, they think that that is their life for their whole life each morning. The man who stayes awake at nights realizes this and at the end it turns out that the whole town is a part of a huge spaceship controlled by the aliens and it turns out that the aliens are performing an experiment on the humans in that spaceship.

This is everything that I know about the movie, it is probably a 80’s or 90’s movie or older, also I know that it was shown in a local TV channel in my country as far as my uncle told me, who knows the same plot as I do and nothing else, thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when for guidance. Great first question. It sounds like a "lighter" version of [Dark City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_City_(1998_film)), but it's not.

Comment: Another vote for Dark City...

Comment: The only part of this that doesn't sound like _Dark City_ is the mention of the story taking place in a  "small town". Everything else is a perfect match.

Comment: Nor does the protagonist in *Dark City* choose to stay awake at night - he just wakes without having his memories fully modified. Other than that, *Dark City* is a good match.

Comment: Ja, Dark City is my guess also.

Comment: @Klaus Æ. Mogensen - Sounds like you're thinking of the start of the movie, when Murdoch wakes up in a bathtub with amnesia. But after that, he is shown as remaining awake when the aliens put everyone else to sleep at midnight. The aliens are at loss as to why this is, but it's presumably related to the powers he was developing, and was implied to be a form of adaptation to his environment.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [*Dark City*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118929/) (1998)?

There's a major plot point about people changing jobs around during the night, with one person waking up (John Murdoch) and realising that this is going on.

Your description ("*it turns out that the whole town is a part of a huge spaceship controlled by the aliens and it turns out that the aliens are performing an experiment on the humans in that spaceship.*") is a pretty solid synopsis of [the ending of the film.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBObeZ6Vj3A)